# block search engines from indexing dev sites

Tags: apache, .htaccess, robots.txt

i think one of my sites recently got delisted from google because it found and started indexing my dev site.  it is basically a replica of my main site.  (dev.site.com & site.com)

anyway, is there a way to create one robot.txt that would prevent any traffic to dev.site.com from being indexed, leaving site.com to still be fully indexed.

i know i could just have separate robot files for each, but it would just be easier to have one that covers both.  especially since i work with a whole of sites which have dev sites, and would just like to have an easy workflow and not have to change the robot files when i push new versions of site to live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could serve the robots.txt file dynamically, e.g. via PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'dev.site.com') {
    echo "...";
} else {
    echo "...";
}
```

Comment: this could work. i actually do my db parameters like this. how would i go about echo'ing a robot.txt file though?  i am a bit confused on what you mean by this.

Comment: I mean just use echo statements to output the lines you want -- e.g., echo "Disallow: /" and so on...

Comment: Alternatively, you could use includes: if (<dev site>) { include "dev-robots.txt"; } else { include "live-robots.txt"; }

Comment: doesnt google just search for the robots.txt in the root? maybe i misunderstand how it works.

Comment: Currently, your Apache is configured to process files named *.php as PHP files. You might also have *.phtml or some other extensions configured in the same manner. Now, if you configure your Apache to process *.txt files as PHP files as well, then you can put PHP in your robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to add a line to your .htaccess file:
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"

This is advocated to be superior to the robots.txt as if there is a link to your dev site the search engines will report the link (even if they do not index your site). This is advocated here:
http://yoast.com/prevent-site-being-indexed/

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the standard that each subdomain must have its own robots.txt (if being accessed from dev.site.com; you wouldn't need another for site.com/dev).